# Compute the operator norm of a generic $2\times 2$ matrix

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with norm $\Vert (x,y) \Vert=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$ I would like to compute the operator norm w.r.t. the above norm of a matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}  \end{pmatrix}.$$

I tried to to compute $\Vert A \Vert=\sup\lbrace{\Vert Av \Vert:\Vert v \Vert=1 \rbrace}$ by using polar coordinates. We can write $v=(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$ for any $v\in S^1.$ Hence we get

$$\Vert Av\Vert^2= \cos( \theta)^2(a_{11}^2+a_{21}^2)+\sin(\theta)^2(a_{12}^2+a_{22}^2)+2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)(a_{11}a_{12}+a_{21}a_{22})=:f(\theta)$$

But I could not compute the maximum of $f(\theta)$. Is there maybe a better way to compute the norm?

Best wishes

Comment: The bottom half of the answer here may be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1422227/260918

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a brute force way:

We have $\|A\| = \sqrt{\lambda_\max(A^T A)}$.

We can compute the eigenvalues using $\det(\lambda I-A^TA) =0$,
which gives
$$\|A\| = \sqrt{
{1 \over 2} \left(a_{22}^2+a_{21}^2+a_{12}^2+a_{11}^2 + \sqrt{a_{22}^4+(2a_{21}^2+2a_{12}^2−2a_{11}^2)a_{22}^2+8a_{11}a_{12}a_{21}a_{22}+a_{21}^4+(2a_{11}^2−2a_{12}^2)a_{21}^2+a_{12}^4+2a_{11}^2a_{12}^2+a_{11}^4} \right)
}$$