# When is $\|Av\|_2 = \|A\|_F\|v\|_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, matrix-norms

Let $\|\cdot\|_F$ be the Frobenius norm on $M_{n\times n}$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. For a given matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}$, what vectors satisfy $\|Av\|_2 = \|A\|_F\|v\|_2$?

I can prove the relation is $\leq$ as follows

$$
\|Av\|_2^2 = \sum\limits_i\left(\sum\limits_j A_{ij}v_j\right)^2 = \sum\limits_i\left(\left<A_i,v\right>\right)^2 \leq \sum\limits_i\|A_i\|_2^2\|v\|_2^2 = \|v\|_2^2 \sum\limits_i\sum\limits_j A_{ij}^2=\|v\|_2^2\|A\|_F^2
$$
where $A_i$ is the $i$-th row of $A$, $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>$ is the standard inner product, and the inequality is due to the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Cauchy Schwartz inequality is an equality if and only if the vectors are linearly dependent. Thus, in order to get an equality, we must have for all $i$, $A_i = \alpha_i v$ for some $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{R}$.

Does this mean that we get an equality if and only if $(i)$ $\det(A)=0$ and $(ii)$ $v$ is a row of $A$?
This is a very strict condition. Is it the only way, or am I missing something?

Comment: I agree with "for all $i$, $A_i = \alpha_i v$ for some $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{R}$" (or $v=0$), but not with your last paragraph. $A$ should be worse (rank $1$) and $v$ should have more freedom (proportio al to $A$'s rows instead of equal to one of them).

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419336) may interest you.